audio dropouts to TV but not AV receiver
When audio passes from PC to TV on HDMI, the audio drops out for a second a few times per minute. (almost like a loss of sync)
If I boot the PC with Ubuntu, Kubuntu, or Mint there are several 1 second dropouts per minute.
If I boot the PC with Win10, Manjaro, or LMDE there is no dropout.
If I pass HDMI directly to the AV receiver there is never a dropout.
I know you want to blame the problem on hardware of the TV but only Ubuntu based configurations have the problem. Music, Youtube, video or any audio application have the same problem.
Since the AV receiver is old, it can't pass 4K or even 1080 x 120Hz so I would prefer the PC to TV configuration. My main application is only available on Ubuntu, so...
I don't know where to look for any errors or misconfigurations.
